# Non Sequential Loop Optimization in Python

Tags: python, optimization, loops, nonsequential

I have two dictionary objects, connections and network. This can be visualized as a graph, where each node is a computer and connections depict an edge between the computers and node. Network is a dictionary objects of unique networks where the computers can be a part, for ex

```
1,2  
2,3  
4,5  
5,1
```

are four connection information for nodes 1 through 1
connections would thus be {1->1,2->1,3->1,4->2,5->1}
and network {1->0,2->1}
which means
computer 1,2,3,5 are part of n/w 1
computer 4 is part of n/w 2
again n/w 2 is interconnected to n/w 1
I have to read a file with thousand of such connection information
while doing so, for each connection info read I have to perform a non-sequential loop as follows

```
while network.has_key(connections[node1]):
    connections[node1]=network[connections[node1]]
```

Is there a better way to optimize the above loop? If required I can share my entire code for the purpose

Comment: What do you mean by "Non-sequential loop"? Presumably, you're reading a single file sequentially, and I'm assuming that is your bottleneck.

Comment: Have you thought of profiling your code? CProfile is great http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html - after that you will have a clear idea of what is your bottleneck

Comment: @oxtopus,  Please check the code snippet. Non-Sequential means neither I can use List Comprehension nor any list functions like reduce ...

Comment: @savinos,  Yes I tried and this is how I identified the above code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while network.has_key(connections[node1]):
    connections[node1]=network[connections[node1]]
```

That code does the lookup for `network[connections[node1]]` twice once for `has_key` and once for `[]`.

It also repeatedly accesses `connections[node1]`

Instead you can do:

```
current = connections[node1]
while True:
    try:
         current = network[current]
    except KeyError:
         break
connections[node1] = current
```

But chances are better improvements can be had be reworking the rest of your code. But for that you may find http://codereview.stackexchange.com to be a better site.

Comment: Stupid of me. I was completely blind on this. I was somehow trying to look into this from a completely different perspective.

Comment: From cProfiler I found this line of code was the bottleneck of my whole system. Reducing 50% of time here could eventually reduce 20% of the processing time.

Comment: @user977038, perhaps but usually you solve that sort of thing by avoiding coming here, not making this faster.

Comment: @user977038, by avoiding coming here, I mean to the piece of code during execution. Don't make this code faster. Call it less.

Answer (score 2):

I'm didn't really understand your question, but I feel the stock answer to graph-related questions applies here:

Use [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) rather than trying to come up with your own data representations and algorithms. It may be harder to learn, but it'll save you time and headaches in the long run.

Comment: I actually used NetworkX to create my initial prototype of the program. Worked perfectly well. Am now trying to code the same without it. Obvious reason performance because of which I am here to optimize every bit I feel have bottlenecks.